# Why won't requestAnimationFrame() work while nested inside this if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a tetris game and right now I'm writing the function that drops the piece every 1s(in this case every 800ms). My function looks like this

```
function drop() {
    //grab the current time
    let now = Date.now();
    //create a var to hold the difference of the current time
    let delta = now - dropStart; //------Why can't these be switched
    if(delta > 800) {
        dropStart = Date.now();
        drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, vacant);
        p.y++;
        drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, p.color);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drop);
}

drop();
```

This does the job just fine. However I'm still a newbie and since I'm copying this code from a tutorial I like to read out the logic top to bottom from a function then rearrange certain lines. For instance I moved the `requestAnimationFrame(drop);` and put it inside the if statement. So it looks like this

```
 function drop() {
    //grab the current time
    let now = Date.now();
    //create a var to hold the difference of the current time
    let delta = now - dropStart; //------Why can't these be switched
    if(delta > 800) {
        dropStart = Date.now();
        drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, vacant);
        p.y++;
        drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, p.color);
        requestAnimationFrame(drop);
    }
}

drop();
```

This will brake the function, and you won't see the tetromino piece fall every 800ms. I looked in the dubugger and watched the function execute. I watched it hit the first drawpiece() function which is suppose to remove the current piece(painting over it with the color black). Then increase its position then draw the new piece in its new position. The problem though is it doesn't remove the piece or paint a new one in its new position. However all of that is fixed when requestAnimationFrame(drop); is moved? Why?

```js
// //create your globals
// const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
// const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// const row = 20;
// const col = 10;
// const sq = 40;
// const vacant = 'black';

// //-----------------------Why can't I initialize the tetrominos??

// //create and draw board
// let board = [];
// for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
//  board[r] = [];
//  for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
//   board[r][c] = vacant;
//   draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
//  }
// }

// //define a function to draw to the canvas
// function draw(x, y, color) {
//  ctx.fillStyle = color;
//  ctx.fillRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
//  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
//  ctx.strokeRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
// }

// //create an object for the tetrominos 
// function Tetromino(tetromino, color) {
//  this.tetromino = tetromino;
//  this.color = color;
//  this.tetrominoN = 0;
//  this.activeTetromino = this.tetromino[this.tetrominoN];
//  this.x = 0;
//  this.y = 0;
// }

// //create an array for the pieces
// const pieces = [
//  [Z, 'red'],
//  [S, 'limegreen'],
//  [T, 'yellow'],
//  [O, 'blue'],
//  [L, '#b938ff'],
//  [I, 'cyan'],
//  [J, 'orange']
// ]

// //create a new instance of Tetromino
// function randomPiece() {
//  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * pieces.length);
//  return new Tetromino(pieces[r][0], pieces[r][1]);
// }
// let p = randomPiece();

// //draw the piece
// function drawPiece(piece) {
//  //loop through the tetromino
//  for(let r = 0; r < piece.length; r++) {
//   for(let c = 0; c < piece.length; c++) {
//    //if the tetromino index is zero skip it
//    if(!piece[r][c]) continue;
//    //else draw it
//    else draw(p.x + c, p.y + r, p.color);
//   }
//  }
// }

// //undrawdraw the piece
// function undrawPiece(piece) {
//  //loop through the tetromino
//  for(let r = 0; r < piece.length; r++) {
//   for(let c = 0; c < piece.length; c++) {
//    //if the tetromino index is zero skip it
//    if(!piece[r][c]) continue;
//    //else draw it
//    else draw(p.x + c, p.y + r, vacant);
//   }
//  }
// }

// drawPiece(p.activeTetromino);

// //control the piece 
// document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
//  if(event.keyCode === 37) p.moveLeft();

//  else if (event.keyCode === 38) p.rotate();

//     else if (event.keyCode === 39) p.moveRight();

//  else if (event.keyCode === 40) p.moveDown();

// });

// Tetromino.prototype.moveDown = function() {
//  if(!this.collision(0, 1, this.activeTetromino)) {
//   undrawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//   this.y++;
//   drawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//  } else {
//   //lock piece and generate a new one
//   this.lock();
//   p = randomPiece();
//  }
// }

// Tetromino.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
//  if(!this.collision(-1, 0, this.activeTetromino)) {
//   undrawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//   this.x--;
//   drawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//  }
// }

// Tetromino.prototype.moveRight = function() {
//  if(!this.collision(1, 0, this.activeTetromino)) {
//   undrawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//   this.x++;
//   drawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//  }
// }

// Tetromino.prototype.rotate = function() {
//  let nextPattern = this.tetromino[(this.tetrominoN + 1) % 4];
//  if(!this.collision(0, 0, nextPattern)) {
//   if(this.tetromino.length > 1) {
//    undrawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//    this.tetrominoN = (this.tetrominoN + 1) % 4; // take paranthesis off
//    this.activeTetromino = this.tetromino[this.tetrominoN];
//    drawPiece(this.activeTetromino);
//   }
//  }
// }

// //create a function to check for collisions
// Tetromino.prototype.collision = function(x, y, piece) {
//  for(let r = 0; r < piece.length; r++) {
//   for(let c = 0; c < piece.length; c++) {
//    //skip index if it is 0
//    if(!piece[r][c]) continue;
//    //create vars for the future piece position
//    let newX = this.x + c + x;
//    let newY = this.y + r + y;
//    //see if new position collides with border
//    if(newX < 0 || newX >= col || newY >= row) return true;
//    //see if there's a locked piece on the board
//    if(board[newY][newX] !== vacant) return true;
//   }
//  }
//  return false;
// }

// Tetromino.prototype.lock = function() {
//  for(let r = 0; r < this.activeTetromino.length; r++) {
//   for(let c = 0; c < this.activeTetromino.length; c++) {
//    if(!this.activeTetromino[r][c]) continue;
//    //if piece reaches the top its gameover
//    if(this.y + r < 0) {
//     gameover = true;
//     alert('Game Over!');
//    }
//    //lock the piece by updating the board
//    board[this.y + r][this.x + c] = this.color;
//   }
//  }
// }

// let dropStart = Date.now();
// //drop the piece every 1s
// function drop() {
//  let now = Date.now();
//  let delta = now - dropStart;
//  //if delta is greater than 1s drop the piece
//  if(delta > 800) {
//   p.moveDown();
//   dropStart = Date.now();
//  }
//  requestAnimationFrame(drop);
// }

// drop();

//declare globals
const col = 10;
const row = 20;
const sq = 40;
const vacant = 'black';
const cvs = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

//create and draw the board
let board = [];
for(let r = 0; r < row; r++) {
 board[r] = [];
 for(let c = 0; c < col; c++) {
  board[r][c] = vacant;
  draw(c, r, board[r][c]);
 }
}

//create a blueprint function to draw to the board
function draw(x, y, color) {
 //set the drawing specifications
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.fillRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
 ctx.strokeRect(x * sq, y * sq, sq, sq);
}

//create a blueprint object for the tetrominos
function Piece(tetromino, color) {
 //create the properties
 this.tetromino = tetromino;
 this.color = color;
 this.tetrominoN = 0;
 this.activeTetromino = this.tetromino[this.tetrominoN];
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
}

//create an array to hold all of the tetrominos
const pieces = [
 [Z, 'red'],
 [S, 'limegreen'],
 [T, 'yellow'],
 [O, 'blue'],
 [L, '#b938ff'],
 [I, 'cyan'],
 [J, 'orange']
]

//grab a piece
let p = new Piece(pieces[2][0], pieces[2][1]);

//create a blueprint function to draw tetrominos to the board
function drawPiece(piece, color) {
 for(let r = 0; r < piece.length; r++) {
  for(let c = 0; c < piece.length; c++) {
   if (!piece[r][c]) continue;
   draw(c + p.x, r + p.y, color);
  }
 }
}

//draw a piece to the board
drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, p.color);

//start a time to set as a refrence for the dropstart
let dropStart = Date.now();
//create a blueprint function to drop the piece
function drop() {
 //grab the current time
 let now = Date.now();
 //create a var to hold the difference of the current time
 let delta = now - dropStart; //------Why can't these be switched
 if(delta > 800) {
  dropStart = Date.now();
  drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, vacant);
  p.y++;
  drawPiece(p.activeTetromino, p.color);
  requestAnimationFrame(drop);
 }
}

drop();
```

```html
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Tetris</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
 body {
  background-color: #595959;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
 }
 canvas {
  outline: 1px solid white;
 }
 .canvas-wrap {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .num-top, .num-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
 }

 .num-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
 }

 .num-bottom {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
 }
 .nb {
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  color: white;
 }
 .num-wrap-t {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
 }
 .num-wrap-b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 800px;
 }
 .num-wrap-b .nb {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 3px;
 }

 .num-wrap-t .nb {
  position: relative;
  top: 31px;
 }
</style>
<body>
 <div class="canvas-wrap">
  <div class="num-top">
   <div class="num-wrap-t">
    <div class="nb">0</div>
    <div class="nb">1</div>
    <div class="nb">2</div>
    <div class="nb">3</div>
    <div class="nb">4</div>
    <div class="nb">5</div>
    <div class="nb">6</div>
    <div class="nb">7</div>
    <div class="nb">8</div>
    <div class="nb">9</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="800"></canvas>
  <div class="num-bottom">
   <div class="num-wrap-b">
    <div class="nb">0</div>
    <div class="nb">1</div>
    <div class="nb">2</div>
    <div class="nb">3</div>
    <div class="nb">4</div>
    <div class="nb">5</div>
    <div class="nb">6</div>
    <div class="nb">7</div>
    <div class="nb">8</div>
    <div class="nb">9</div>
    <div class="nb">10</div>
    <div class="nb">11</div>
    <div class="nb">12</div>
    <div class="nb">13</div>
    <div class="nb">14</div>
    <div class="nb">15</div>
    <div class="nb">16</div>
    <div class="nb">17</div>
    <div class="nb">18</div>
    <div class="nb">19</div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>  
 <script src="tetrominos.js"></script>
 <script src="tetris.js"></script>
</body>
</html> -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Tetris</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>
 body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 body {
  background-color: #595959;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

 canvas {
  outline: 1px solid white;
 }
 .canvas-wrap {
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .num-top, .num-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
 }

 .num-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
 }

 .num-bottom {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
 }
 .nb {
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  color: white;
 }
 .num-wrap-t {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
 }
 .num-wrap-b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 800px;
 }
 .num-wrap-b .nb {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 3px;
 }

 .num-wrap-t .nb {
  position: relative;
  top: 31px;
 }
</style>
<body>
 <div class="canvas-wrap">
  <div class="num-top">
   <div class="num-wrap-t">
    <div class="nb">0</div>
    <div class="nb">1</div>
    <div class="nb">2</div>
    <div class="nb">3</div>
    <div class="nb">4</div>
    <div class="nb">5</div>
    <div class="nb">6</div>
    <div class="nb">7</div>
    <div class="nb">8</div>
    <div class="nb">9</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="800"></canvas>
  <div class="num-bottom">
   <div class="num-wrap-b">
    <div class="nb">0</div>
    <div class="nb">1</div>
    <div class="nb">2</div>
    <div class="nb">3</div>
    <div class="nb">4</div>
    <div class="nb">5</div>
    <div class="nb">6</div>
    <div class="nb">7</div>
    <div class="nb">8</div>
    <div class="nb">9</div>
    <div class="nb">10</div>
    <div class="nb">11</div>
    <div class="nb">12</div>
    <div class="nb">13</div>
    <div class="nb">14</div>
    <div class="nb">15</div>
    <div class="nb">16</div>
    <div class="nb">17</div>
    <div class="nb">18</div>
    <div class="nb">19</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="tetrominos.js"></script>  
 <script src="tetris.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if `delta <= 800` then it won't be called - ever again, so delta will never become > 800, because the code is never called again ... requestAnimationFrame calls the given function once and once only ... to call it again, you must requestAnimationFrame again ... and since you don't then nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question simply: in the example where the `requestAnimationFrame(drop)` is nested inside the if statement, the if condition is never satisfied.

The function relies on having an animation loop happening, or the entire `drop()` function will only run once, see that delta is not 800, ignore the code inside it's block, and never run again.

When requestAnimationFrame() is outside the if statement, it will ALWAYS run and it creates a neverending loop of `drop()` happening, and everytime it runs, `now` and `delta` are being increased by however many milliseconds it took the function to run, and it will eventually be 800 milliseconds greater than `dropStart`, finally satisfying the statement, it will then first reset the time variables to be essentially the same, and then animate the tetris piece moving one space.

Comment: actually nvm, I'm still a bit confused lol. You said that the answer is simply because the if condition is never satisfied. but as I watch it continually go into to the if statement it is. I cans see Delta is always growing higher and higher so it the if statement is always gonna be satisfied since delta will always be greater than > 800. I'm sorry if I'm missing the bigger picture. I think I'd learn better if you wrote out your answer in procedural steps like a program so I can see what happens at the beginning and the all the steps to get to the end

Comment: Or when you say the if condition is never satisfied do you mean it is never fully finished becouse I have the requestAnimationFrame(drop) causing a never ending loop?

Comment: Sorry if I was being confusing, I was talking about when requestAnimationFrame is inside the nested if statement. You want the never ending loop (when `requestAnimationFrame()` is outside the if statement) because that is what increases `delta` in order to eventually pass the condition. I edited my answer to be more concise and explicit.